# CSS translateY is extending document length

Tags: javascript, css, transform

I'm attempting to use CSS to translate my site's content off screen and animate it in when the document is loaded.

But when loading the page, the document length vertically stretches to the bottom of where the content is being translated to. This seems to go away after being on the page a little while, but I would obviously like to remove this issue all together.

Here is the styling I have on the content, which gets the class `.load` added when the page is finished loading.

```
main {
    transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,100%,0);
    transition: transform 800ms cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.12,.96);
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 800ms cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.12,.96);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 800ms cubic-bezier(.17,.67,.12,.96);
}
main.load {
    transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

I've done similar things several times with no issues but I can't seem to figure out what's different about this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the `<body>` should be `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: then I can't scroll at all :(

Answer (score 1):

Your options:

1. Using `z-index` and overlapping content, have content where the translated element is to cover it up. When it's scrolled to you can translate it out from under the other element.
2. Translate in from the side instead. This way you can use `overflow-x:hidden` and still be able to scroll vertically
3. Using `display:none`, `transition: opacity .3s` (with prefixes), and `opacity:0`, wait until the element is visible on the page (detected with javascript) and then change to `display:block` and `opacity:1`
4. Absolutely position the element. This will take the element out of the flow, thus not taking up room for the scroll (**recommended**)

Also, there's no reason to use `translate3d`, you can just use `translateY(100%)` and it won't force hardware acceleration

Comment: thanks for all of this! got it figured out and surprisingly the absolute position didn't do what I needed when I tried that. (should have mentioned my other attempts in my question)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a wrapper div that is height 100% that is overflow-hidden. You can still have content below this wrapper div.

http://jsfiddle.net/2HuLw/1/

HTML

```
<div id="main" class="loading">

    <div id="inner" class="loading">
        <p>intro content.</p>
    </div>


</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    document.querySelector('#inner').classList.remove('loading');

})
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

#main {
    background: orange;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#inner {
    background: red;
    transition-duration: 600ms;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;    
}
#inner.loading {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('main').ready(function(){ 
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('main').addClass('load');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('body').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('body').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
            },1);
        },800);
    },500);
});
```

This may be sloppy but it works

800ms is the time it takes for the animation so once it's in place, it hits the overflow property and then again 1ms after.

Tried many combinations of functions and this is all that worked.

Comment: This is a terrible way to do it as `setTimeout`s are relatively unpredictable in how long they actually last. There is no reason for this much javascript when it can be easily avoided